# Vue.js parsing directive within vue-markdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, directive

I am rendering an `<a />` with a directive using `vue-markdown`.

When my App loads, it seems that my Vue instance is not parsing my rendered tag and thus not calling the appropriate directive.

I'm wondering if there is a prop i need to pass to the `vue-markdown` instance that will allow the Vue parser to pick up my 'nested' directive.

see example below.

```js
import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown'

const Foo = Vue.directive('foo', el => console.log('Element with directive', el));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { VueMarkdown },
  directives: {
    Foo
  }
})
```

```html
<template>
<div id="app">
  <vue-markdown :html="true" source="<a href='/foo' v-foo>I have a directive</a>"></vue-markdown>
  // ^output^ <a href="/url" v-foo>I have a directive</a>
  // This <a /> is NOT registered as an element with a directive and NOT logged out.
  

  <a href="/anotherURL" v-foo>I also have a directive</a> 
  // ^This^ IS registered as an alement with a directive and logged out.
</div>
</template>
```